# php session id not matching

Tags: php, session

session id is not unique between `1.php` and `2.php`.

`1.php` basically sets `$_SESSION['var'] = "hello"`

and `2.php`: `print_r($_SESSION['var'])`

echoing out `session_id()` shows different `id`. same browser (firefox).

everything was working fine, until I screwed up the `.htaccess`. I deleted `.htacces`s and restarted apache2.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you most likely need to set the session.save_path for PHP.

[PHP: session_ save_ path reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sessions on PHP have always caused issues for me, these days I have moved onto the Zend Framework which has a `Zend_Session` component that takes care of most of the issues for me and I have to do less thinking. Take a look and see if that would work for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [PHP session id's differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371649/php-session-ids-differ/1371823#1371823)

--edit--

"everything was working file...until you messesd up with .htaccess" : it means you had some kind of internal redirection setup in there. Take a look at http://enarion.net/web/apache/htaccess/redirect-www-and-no-www/

Answer (score 0):

You use $var variable somewhere in your code either on 1.php or on 2.php Try to change the $var to `$some_thing_else`

When you use $_SESSION this is common problem.